# Tic-Tac-Toe Game: How do I prevent the "It's a tie" alert when winning when all tiles are filled?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code for a Tic-Tac-Toe game using the HTML5 Canvas:

```
    //Global Variables
    var filled;
    var content;
    var winningCombos;
    var turn = 0;
    var tilesFilled = 0;


    window.onload=function(){

        filled = new Array();           //An array for checking if the tile contains content (Xs or Os) to prevent it from being reused
        content = new Array();          //An array for checking what the tile content is (Xs or Os) to determine a winner
        winningCombos = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]];  //A dual array of the 8 different winning combos (3 across, 3 down, 2 diagonal)
        for(var l = 0; l <= 8; l++){        //A for loop, which starts out as unfilled and blank, to assign values to the tiles incrementally
        filled[l] = false;
        content[l]='';
        }
    }       

    //The Canvas and Tiles Function
    function canvasClicked(canvasNumber){               //This will get the number from canvasClicked in the html body
        var theTile = "canvas"+canvasNumber;            //And then append “canvas” to the number. This equals the canvas id.
        var c = document.getElementById(theTile);
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");               //This is adding 2d context to theTile (canvas id)

        // Filling in the Tiles
        if(filled[canvasNumber-1] ==false){         //If the tile is empty

            if(turn%2==0){                  //Determine whose turn it is by the modulo operator

                ctx.beginPath();            //Drawing the X     
                ctx.moveTo(20,20);
                ctx.lineTo(80,80);
                ctx.moveTo(80,20);
                ctx.lineTo(20,80);
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.strokeStyle="palevioletred";
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
                content[canvasNumber-1] = 'X';
            }

            else{                       //If it isn’t Xs turn, then it’s Os turn

                ctx.beginPath();            //Drawing the O     
                ctx.arc(50,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.strokeStyle="skyblue";
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
                content[canvasNumber-1] = 'O';  
            }

            turn++;                     //Alternate Xs and Os turn by using the increment operator, starting with 0 in the global variable turn
            filled[canvasNumber-1] = true;
            tilesFilled++;                  //Checks whether all tiles are filled yet, again with the increment operator, starting at 0 in the variable tilesFilled 
            checkForWinners(content[canvasNumber-1]);   //Check for winners

            if(tilesFilled==9) {                //If there is no winner after all tiles are filled start a new game
                alert("It's a Tie!");
                location.reload(true);
            }

        }

    }

    function checkForWinners(symbol){

        for(var i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++){  //This for loop will go through the 8 winningCombos

        //This will go through all the winningCombos to see whether the 0,1,2 within the index have the same content (Xs or Os)
        if(content[winningCombos[i][0]]==symbol&&content[winningCombos[i][1]]==symbol&&content[winningCombos[i][2]]==symbol){
            alert(symbol+ " WON THE GAME!");
            location.reload(true);
        }
        }

    }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        <canvas id = "canvas1"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(1)"></canvas>
        <canvas id = "canvas2"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(2)"></canvas>
        <canvas id = "canvas3"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(3)"></canvas><br/>
        <canvas id = "canvas4"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(4)"></canvas>
        <canvas id = "canvas5"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(5)"></canvas>
        <canvas id = "canvas6"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(6)"></canvas><br/>
        <canvas id = "canvas7"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(7)"></canvas>
        <canvas id = "canvas8"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(8)"></canvas>
        <canvas id = "canvas9"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(9)"></canvas>
</body>
```

Essentially, the "It's a tie" alert will run when all 9 tiles are filled.  However, when a win is achieved when the 9th tile is filled, this will also generate the "It's a tie" alert.  How do I prevent this?

Also, any and all advice on how to improve this code is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//Global Variables
var filled;
var content;
var winningCombos;
var turn = 0;
var tilesFilled = 0;


window.onload=function(){

  filled = new Array();           //An array for checking if the tile contains content (Xs or Os) to prevent it from being reused
  content = new Array();          //An array for checking what the tile content is (Xs or Os) to determine a winner
  winningCombos = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]];  //A dual array of the 8 different winning combos (3 across, 3 down, 2 diagonal)
  for(var l = 0; l <= 8; l++){        //A for loop, which starts out as unfilled and blank, to assign values to the tiles incrementally
    filled[l] = false;
    content[l]='';
  }
}       

//The Canvas and Tiles Function
function canvasClicked(canvasNumber){               //This will get the number from canvasClicked in the html body
  var theTile = "canvas"+canvasNumber;            //And then append “canvas” to the number. This equals the canvas id.
  var c = document.getElementById(theTile);
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");               //This is adding 2d context to theTile (canvas id)

  // Filling in the Tiles
  if(filled[canvasNumber-1] ==false){         //If the tile is empty

    if(turn%2==0){                  //Determine whose turn it is by the modulo operator

      ctx.beginPath();            //Drawing the X     
      ctx.moveTo(20,20);
      ctx.lineTo(80,80);
      ctx.moveTo(80,20);
      ctx.lineTo(20,80);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle="palevioletred";
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      content[canvasNumber-1] = 'X';
    }

    else{                       //If it isn’t Xs turn, then it’s Os turn

      ctx.beginPath();            //Drawing the O     
      ctx.arc(50,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle="skyblue";
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      content[canvasNumber-1] = 'O';  
    }

    turn++;                     //Alternate Xs and Os turn by using the increment operator, starting with 0 in the global variable turn
    filled[canvasNumber-1] = true;
    tilesFilled++;                  //Checks whether all tiles are filled yet, again with the increment operator, starting at 0 in the variable tilesFilled 
    var winnerName = checkForWinners(content[canvasNumber-1]);//Check for winners

    if(tilesFilled == 9 && winnerName == "undefined") {                //If there is no winner after all tiles are filled start a new game
      alert("GAME OVER!");
      location.reload(true);
    }else if(winnerName != "undefined"){
      alert(winnerName+ " WON THE GAME!");
      location.reload(true);
    }

  }

}

function checkForWinners(symbol){

  for(var i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++){  //This for loop will go through the 8 winningCombos

    //This will go through all the winningCombos to see whether the 0,1,2 within the index have the same content (Xs or Os)
    if(content[winningCombos[i][0]]==symbol&&content[winningCombos[i][1]]==symbol&&content[winningCombos[i][2]]==symbol){
      return symbol; break;
      //location.reload(true);
    }
  }
  return "undefined";

}
```

```html
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<canvas id = "canvas1"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(1)"></canvas>
<canvas id = "canvas2"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(2)"></canvas>
<canvas id = "canvas3"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(3)"></canvas><br/>
<canvas id = "canvas4"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(4)"></canvas>
<canvas id = "canvas5"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(5)"></canvas>
<canvas id = "canvas6"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(6)"></canvas><br/>
<canvas id = "canvas7"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(7)"></canvas>
<canvas id = "canvas8"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(8)"></canvas>
<canvas id = "canvas9"  width="100" height="100" onclick="canvasClicked(9)"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you print that it's a tie.  However I would change this method call:

```
checkForWinners(content[canvasNumber-1]);
```

to return a boolean, and it would be true if the alert inside that method is called.

Then change this:

```
if(tilesFilled==9) {
```

to say

```
if(noWinnersAlertBoolean && tilesFilled==9) {
```